# Can't reach results of Papa Parse outside the 'complete' function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, papaparse

I am currently using Papa Parse with Angular 2 to load a csv list into a list and I want to be able to pass that list through to another component. I am able to read the csv data and print them with a console log but I am unable to address the results of the parsed data outside the 'complete' function. I know that this is because parsing a file is a asynchronous process and that I have to work with a callback function. I tried to fix this with a callback function but I am still not able to use the data outside the 'complete' function from Papa Parse itself.

This is an example of something I tried, but here the listOfLoads is undefined in the convertloads method, not in any other normal synchronous method.

```
export class AppComponent {


 listOfLoads: Load[] = [];

  constructor(){
  }

  importFile(fileInput: any, callBack) {
    let listOfLoads: Load[] = [];
    let file = fileInput.target.files[0];


    let result = Papa.parse(fileInput.target.files[0], {
      complete: function (results) {
        callBack(results.data);
      },
      header: true,
      delimiter: ";"
    });
  }

  convertLoads(data) {
    this.listOfLoads = deserialize<Load[]>(Load, data);
  }

}
```

Is there a way to put the data in a list and use it in an other component? I've searched everywhere for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give your component function to Papaparse.
Once Papaparse loads data it will trigger your function.
Or you can create an observable and when data load completed you can do whatever want in subscribe block.

I created a working plunkr for you. You can look at this.

[https://plnkr.co/edit/WFVYEQnH35DeTsNBS456](http://s)

Comment: The observable example worked perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ömer's answer (accepted above) is correct, but five years later, is a bit dated and can use with additional context. I submitted the following as an edit to his answer but my edits were rejected for whatever reason. Anyway, the 2022 update to his answer:

You can give your component function to Papa Parse, outside of the config. Once Papa Parse loads data it will trigger your function. Here's an example of where they do this in their [demo](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/player/player.js#L104).

Or, with Angular it is preferable to observe data and react to the stream, rather than using callbacks. Again, once the data is loaded, you can do whatever you want, but this time in the `subscribe` block. Or alter the stream as you would any other observable (i.e. with `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, `tap`, etc., etc.).

Check out this [Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFVYEQnH35DeTsNBS456) for how to do this with Angular 2.

Or, updated for 2022 using "modern" Angular and rxjs -- do something like this:

```js
import {parse, ParseResult} from 'papaparse'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

// [...]

parseCsv(file: File): Observable<ParseResult<any>> {
    return new Observable(observable => {
        parse(file, {
            // dynamicTyping: true,
            // header: true,
            // See: https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config
            complete: (results) => {
                observable.next(results);
                observable.complete();
            }
        });
    });
}

// [...]

anyMethod(): void { // or, something like like ngOnInit()

    // Get the file string or reference (i.e. local/remote file).
    // See: https://www.papaparse.com/docs#csv-to-json
    const file = // Whatever you do to get the file reference.

    parseCsv(file).subscribe(p => {
        console.log(p.data);
        // Do something with the data.
    })
}
```

As always: Don't forget to `unsubscribe` or you'll risk introducing memory leaks.